# Find Row Index on DataTable

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

Is it possible to get the row index of a DataTable so that you can access the previous and next row? For example I have a DataTable that contains two columns ChapterTitle and PageURL. This is for a table of contents of a book. ChapterTitle is the chapter name and PageURL is an HTML page that contains the chapter (chaptername.html). When going into one chapter of the book I want to be able to tell which is the next and previous chapter.

After finding the chapter that I'm currently in how can get the next and previous rows?

```
ChapterTable.Select("PageURL = '" & PageURL& "'")
```

Comment: You say you have two columns: `ChapterTitle` and `PageURL`, but you`re selecting the column `ChapterStartPage`.

Comment: either you have the info in your dataBase, either you'll have to parse your ChapterTitle to find the info...   (reminder : the order of the rows in a DataBase should not be relevant. Primary key(s) are.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Private Sub LoadDataAndFindRow
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("ChapterTitle")
dt.Columns.Add("PageURL")

Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
dr(0) = "Aarons Book"
dr(1) = "www.AaronsBook.com"
dt.Rows.Add(dr)

dr = dt.NewRow()
dr(0) = "Tims Book"
dr(1) = "www.TimsBook.com"
dt.Rows.Add(dr)

dr = dt.NewRow()
dr(0) = "vincents Book"
dr(1) = "www.vincentsBook.com"
dt.Rows.Add(dr)

dr = dt.NewRow()
dr(0) = "Xi's Book"
dr(1) = "www.XisBook.com"
dt.Rows.Add(dr)

Dim i As Integer = FindRow(dt, "Tims Book")
Dim prevRowID As Integer = i - 1
Dim nextRowID As Integer = i + 1

End Sub


Function FindRow(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal chapterTitle As String) As Integer
For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count
If dt.Rows(i)("ChapterTitle") = chapterTitle Then Return i
Next
Return -1
End Function
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a loop?

Comment: I first tried using LINQ on the datatable.AsEnumerable() with a Skip(-1).Take(3), but it was taking up too much time to get it working. Another thought is to have a third column in your DataTable called RowID and then you can use the .Select method as shown in your question and with the RowID -1 or +1 you'll know the Prev and Next rows in the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the dt.Columns.PrimaryKey() when you draw up the table, you can just use findby(pk)  if you set that then you can use LINQ easily, just:
' we'll name the datatable chapters to keep readable:

```
dim query = from  chapters in dt.AsEnumerable _
             where chapters("chapterTitle").equals(<<your criteria>>) _
             select chapters

newDT = iif(chapters.count > 0, chapters.copyToDataTable(), nothing)
```

You can modify or just get the chapters.toDataRow..etc.

HTH